# Display EmbedsMany Data in Laravel MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I have a database with schemes like below:

```
{
    "title": "Simple new",
    "username": "soimah",
    "_id": ObjectId("5569b157bed33066220041ac"),
    "comments": [{
    "subject": "comment 1",
    "_id": ObjectId("5569cc28bed330693eb7acd9")
    }]
}
```

I would like to display the title and subject.

My Model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class Testo extends Eloquent {
    protected $collection = 'testIN';
    protected $fillable = array('title', 'comments.subject');

    public function comments() {
    return $this - > embedsMany('comments');
    }
}
?>
```

My Controller:

```
public function ambl() {
    $g = new Testo();
    $g = Testo::where('username', '=', 'soimah') - > first() - > comments;
    return View('layouts/in', array(
    'g' => $g
    ));
}
```

My View :

```
<?php
    foreach($g as $j) {
      echo $j['comments.subject'];
    }
?>
```

Data comments.

```
subject not show.
```

Please help me to show them.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues there.

1. The method `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model::embedsMany()` expects parameter 1 to be the fully qualified name of another model, just like `hasMany` in Eloquent does.
   You should create a Model `Comment` and adjust your Testo model to the following:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Models;

   use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

   class Testo extends Eloquent 
   {
       protected $collection = 'testIN';

       protected $fillable = array('title', 'comments.subject');

       public function comments()
       {
           return $this->embedsMany(Comment::class);
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your view, the variable `$j` should then be an instance of `Comment`. You can access the subject of a comment like this:

   ```
   // Raw PHP view:
   <?php
   foreach ($g as $j) 
   {
       echo $j->subject;
   }
   ?>

   // Blade syntax:
   @foreach($g as $j)
       {{ $j->subject }}
   @endforeach
   ```

For further reading, please have a look at the offical `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` documentation, section `Embeds Many Relations`:

https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#embedsmany-relations

Comment: Can you add `Comment` model also here.. Please. Im stuck with the same isssue

Comment: Can you add comment model also brother?